# ASP.NET ListView Tab Event triggers verification button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listview

I'm working with ASP.Net ListView, where the user can enter Partnumbers and verify them by the click on the verification button. Now i want to trigger that button when the user presses the TAB Key. The important thing is that the tab key event only happens in the ListView. I understand that i need to do it with javascript but i dont know how to trigger the ListView Button.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Width="700" Height="200">
<telerik:RadListView runat="server"
    ID="RadListView_NewProposal"
    ItemPlaceholderID="RadListView_NewProposal_ItemPlaceholder"
    AllowPaging="True"
    OnItemDataBound="RadListView_NewProposal_ItemDataBound"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadListView_NewProposal_NeedDataSource">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server">
            <asp:Table runat="server" CssClass="mainTable">

                <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server" ForeColor="Red">
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell>&nbsp;</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="test_table">Partnumber</asp:TableHeaderCell>

                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="RadListView_NewProposal_ItemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>

                <asp:TableFooterRow runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3">
                        <telerik:RadDataPager ID="RadDataPagerProducts" runat="server" PageSize="5">
                            <Fields>
                                <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric"></telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField>
                            </Fields>
                        </telerik:RadDataPager>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableFooterRow>

            </asp:Table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Visible")%>'>
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" ForeColor="Teal">
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="LF_Proposal_Buttons">
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnVerify" CssClass="rlvBEdit" ToolTip="Material Nummer überprüfen." ImageUrl="images/Column-Add_Small.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Key") %>'
                        OnCommand="btnVerify_Command" />
                    &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="rlvBDelete" ToolTip="Eintrag Löschen." ImageUrl="images/Delete_Small.png" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Key") %>'
                                OnCommand="btnDelete_Command" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="LF_Proposal_Partnr">
                    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox runat="server" ID="cbPartnumber" DropDownWidth="240px" DropDownHeight="160px"
                        Filter="StartsWith" InputType="Text" OnClientTextChanged="cbPartnumber_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"
                         >
                    </telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

Comment: So the proposed flow is... User tabs through form fields, gets to part number field, enters part number and then tabs to the next field. Correct? And the field you are concerned with is `cbPartnumber`?

Comment: Not quite, user types in Partnumber in the `cbPartnumber` field and than triggers the `btnVerify` Button with the Tab key.

Comment: Is there a reason they are triggering the button with the tab key rather than clicking on it or pressing enter as is normal/expected form behaviour?

Comment: The site is for people who are used to use SAP and the UI should be as close to SAP as possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try...

Add a CSS class to the `cbPartnumber` field, let's assume it's `part-number`.

Then in your JavaScript (assume you're using jQuery):

```
$(".part-number").blur(function () {
    $(".rlvBEdit").trigger("click");
});
```

What this will do is every time a user clicks/tabs into the part number input then clicks/tabs out, a click will be triggered on the verify button.